# ReactNative,How to get position FlatList Item in ScrollView

Tags: react-native

I would like to scroll the parent `ScrollView` to that item`position` when I click Item in `FlatList`.

Since the actual data is flexible in length, can not calculate the height statically.

```
<ScrollView>
  <View style={{height:300}}>
    <Text>Test</Text>
  </View>
  <FlatList
    scrollEnabled={false}
    data={[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]}
    renderItem={renderItem}
  />
</ScrollView>
```

`ScrollToIndex` in a `FlatList` can not be used because `scrollEnabled` is `false`.
I want to use `ScrollTo` of the parent `ScrollView`.

But `onLayout` is used for`renderItem`, `y` is 0.
So I do not know the exact position.

How can I get the value I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, Don't use FlatList inside ScrollView, use ListHeaderComponent prop in FlatList

Reference: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#listheadercomponent